Tiktok API returns an error "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
{'error': 'Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'}
My code first worked then it gave this error, please help, here is my code:
import requests


def req(url, headers, params):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
        response.raise_for_status()  # HTTP hatalarını kontrol eder

        if response.text.strip():  # Yanıtın boş olup olmadığını kontrol eder
            return response.json()
        else:
            return {"error": "Boş yanıt alındı."}
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        return {"error": str(e)}
    except ValueError as e:  # JSON dönüşüm hatalarını yakalar
        return {"error": "Geçersiz JSON yanıt: " + str(e)}


def infos_mytich():
    # Kullanıcıdan gerekli bilgileri alıyoruz
    user_id = input("Lütfen user_id girin: ")

    sec_user_id = input("Lütfen sec_user_id girin: ")

    url = "https://api31-normal-alisg.tiktokv.com/aweme/v1/user/following/list/"

    params = {
        'user_id': user_id,
        'sec_user_id': sec_user_id,
        'max_time': '1',
        'count': 50,
        'offset': '10',
        'source_type': '3',
        'address_book_access': '1',
        'live_sort_by': '1',
        'ios': 'android',
        '_rticket': '1672938472994',
        'is_pad': '1',
        'host_abi': 'x86_64',
        'ts': '1678326735',
    }

    headers = {
        'Host': 'api31-normal-alisg.tiktokv.com',
        'X-Tt-Multi-Sids': '123456789%3Aabcdefg0987654321',
        'Sdk-Version': '3',
        'X-Bd-Kmsv': '1',
        'X-Ss-Req-Ticket': '9923748374737',
        'Multi_login': '0',
        'Passport-Sdk-Version': '30',
        'X-Tt-Dm-Status': 'login=0;ct=0;rt=0',
        'X-Vc-Bdturing-Sdk-Version': '3.0.0',
        'X-Tt-Store-Region': 'ca',
        'X-Tt-Store-Region-Src': 'ip',
        'Rpc-Persist-Pyxis-Policy-V-Tnc': '0',
        'X-Ss-Dp': '5678',
        'X-Tt-Trace-Id': '00-bc123ef4567890ab-cd123ef4567890ab-01',
        'User-Agent': 'com.zhiliaoapp.musically/2024101010 (Linux; U; Android 12; en_US; Pixel 6; Build/SD1A.210817.037; Cronet/112.0.5615.136)',
        'X-Khronos': '1672938472',
        'X-Common-Params-V2': 'ab_version=31.5.3&ac=WIFI&ac2=wifi&aid=1233&app_language=en&app_name=musical_ly&app_type=normal&build_number=40.0.0&cdid=abcd1234-5678-90ef-1234-567890abcdef&channel=googleplay&current_region=US&device_brand=Google&device_id=1234567890123456789&device_platform=android&device_type=Pixel+6&dpi=440&iid=9876543210987654321&language=en&locale=en-US&manifest_version_code=400000&op_region=US&openudid=abcd1234ef567890&os_api=31&os_version=12&region=US&residence=US&resolution=1080*2400&ssmix=a&sys_region=US&timezone_name=America%2FLos_Angeles&timezone_offset=-28800&uoo=0&update_version_code=2024101010&version_code=401000&version_name=40.0.0',
    }

    response = req(url, headers, params)

    if "error" in response:
        print(f"Hata: {response['error']}")
    else:
        print(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    infos_mytich
()

{'error': 'Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'}
My code worked first then it gave this error.
